# Convert a few column cells of an excel into rows while maintaining others cell as rows

Tags: excel

I have this data in an excel file

[image]

I need to convert this to this:

[image]

So the resultant form should like this

[image]

Any of the following forms are acceptable as well.

[image]
**OR**
[image]

Any ideas on how to achieve this:

Comment: The 3rd printscreen: shouldn't that be score a, score b , score c??

Comment: Was this answered btw?

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple unpivot operation on columns Score A,B and C.

You can do with VBA SQL or, if you have Excel 2013 onwards use Powerquery. 
Data tab (Get and Transform Excel 2016) or PowerQuery tab Excel 2013.

Note: This applies to Windows machines not Macs.

Select your data > Data from table > Select last 3 columns  > Right click select Unpivot columns > Rename Attribute column as Score and Value column as Scores. > Close and load to sheet

Example:

[image: Unpivot]

And not wanting to recreate the wheel, the following by  [IoanCosmin](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-vba-macros/149219-equivalent-of-power-query-unpivot-columns-in-vba) works. I have adapted for your example assuming your data starts in sheet1 cell A1.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim p

    'get the unpivoted data as a 2-D array
    p = UnPivotData(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                    2, True, False)

    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    For r = 1 To UBound(p, 1)

        For c = 1 To UBound(p, 2)
            Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, c).Value = p(r, c)
        Next c

    Next r

End Sub

Function UnPivotData(rngSrc As Range, fixedCols As Long, _
                     Optional AddCategoryColumn As Boolean = True, _
                     Optional IncludeBlanks As Boolean = True)

    Dim nR As Long, nC As Long, data, dOut()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, rOut As Long, cOut As Long, cat As Long
    Dim outRows As Long, outCols As Long

    data = rngSrc.Value                          'get the whole table as a 2-D array
    nR = UBound(data, 1)                         'how many rows
    nC = UBound(data, 2)                         'how many cols

    'calculate the size of the final unpivoted table
    outRows = nR * (nC - fixedCols)
    outCols = fixedCols + IIf(AddCategoryColumn, 2, 1)

    'resize the output array
    ReDim dOut(1 To outRows, 1 To outCols)

    'populate the header row
    For c = 1 To fixedCols
        dOut(1, c) = data(1, c)
    Next c
    If AddCategoryColumn Then
        dOut(1, fixedCols + 1) = "Month"
        dOut(1, fixedCols + 2) = "Amount"
    Else
        dOut(1, fixedCols + 1) = "Amount"
    End If


    'populate the data
    rOut = 1
    For r = 2 To nR
        For cat = fixedCols + 1 To nC


            If IncludeBlanks Or Len(data(r, cat)) > 0 Then
                rOut = rOut + 1
                'Fixed columns...
                For c = 1 To fixedCols
                    dOut(rOut, c) = data(r, c)
                Next c
                'populate unpivoted values
                If AddCategoryColumn Then
                    dOut(rOut, fixedCols + 1) = data(1, cat)
                    dOut(rOut, fixedCols + 2) = data(r, cat)
                Else
                    dOut(rOut, fixedCols + 1) = data(r, cat)
                End If
            End If

        Next cat
    Next r

    UnPivotData = dOut
End Function
```

---

For 2013 you need to download the [Powerquery free add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=39379) from Microsoft and then use the powerquery tab rather than Get & Transform.

Comment: In Excel 2013, I don't see a "Get & Transform" section under the Data tab.

Comment: 2013 use the powerquery tab. You will need to download the free add-in for 2013 from Microsoft.

Comment: Link added to answer at the bottom.

Comment: Instead of un-pivoting, does PowerQuery support doing the reverse and pivoting data? (I'm essentially trying to resolve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097773/transpose-multiple-rows-to-multiple-columns), only for a much larger file)

Comment: It sure does. The pivot functionality is found in the transform tab (rather than the home) I think though I haven't used 2013 in a while!